# What is the name of the Google PageSpeed User Agent?

Tags: user-agent, google-pagespeed

[This page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/faq#whyonlinediff) indicates that it uses a custom user agent but it does not mention the name. I would like to be able to run some logic if the user agent is from PageSpeed. What is the name of the Google PageSpeed user agent?

Answer (score 15):

The information in other answers is outdated: currently, Google PageSpeed does not pass the «**Google Page Speed Insights**» string in its `User-Agent` HTTP header, it passes the «**Chrome-Lighthouse**» string instead.
An example:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3464.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Please note that the string is exactly «**Chrome-Lighthouse**» even if you run Google PageSpeed in other browsers (e.g. Firefox).

Comment: Probably outdated now too, just tried it and neither **"Google Page Speed Insights"** or 
 **"Chrome-Lighthouse"**  work.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Page Speed Insights powered by Lighthouse uses a default userAgent, that cannot be detected anymore :(

Comment: @PapaSoft that may have been true in June '20 but either way the API sends a 'Chrome-Lighthouse' user agent now (March '21)

Comment: @Jake1986 Right now PageSpeed *says* it sends a user-agent with "Chrome-Lighthouse", but in reality it doesn't do this at all. I echoed the user-agent and it was a completely different one. It didn't include anything like "lighthouse" or "pagespeed".

Answer (score 8):

I created a script, it returns two USER AGENT one for desktop and other for mobile, these are

for MOBILE:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Mobile Safari/537.36

FOR DESKTOP

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 7):

In 2020 :

1. Chrome-Lighthouse : for mobile
2. Google Page Speed Insights : for desktop

Answer (score 7):

May 2020, there you go:

Mobile:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Mo
>   to G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Desktop:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Comment: It is valid on 2022, except it is not "Mo to", but "Moto.

Answer (score 6):

## Update for March 2023

**Google Page Speed Insights** updated instance of **Lighthouse** to version **10.x** and this event changes **User-Agents**:

**For mobile**:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; moto g power (2022)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

**For Desktop**:

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Passing **Chrome-Lighthouse** string has been stopped.

More details is here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/14384

Comment: Oh no... now we have to remove all Google products that ***really*** were the cause for low LH scores.

Google Analytics, Google Ad Manager, Google Tag Manager, Google AdSense just to name a few.

Without these it was always 80-90%+ on LH.

I guess it's 2 teams at Google. One that works on improving performance and one that kills it. Someone needs to get the two in touch, LOL...

Comment: I checked the access_logs today and they still included 'Chrome-Lighthouse' in the UA.

Answer (score 5):

I have just made a test, requested my site and checkout logs in real time.

User-Agent logs

#### Web Client test: @ https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed

```
date : "21/Feb/21"
user-agent-mobile : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.175 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse",
user-agent-desktop :  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.175"
```

---

#### [node-cli](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli) `lighthouse --version` @ 7.1.0:

```
command : `lighthouse example.com --view`
date : "21/Feb/21"
user-agent-mobile : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse",
user-agent-desktop :  "Mozilla/5.0 ($ENV_OS) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/$ENV_CHROME Safari/537.36"
```

Note that for the `user-agent-desktop` in the `node-cli` for test, there are two variables **`$ENV_OS`**  and **`$ENV_CHROME`**  which will vary according to the running envirmoent.

Comment: I just checked my access logs after running the API in both desktop and mobile and can confirm this is correct.

Answer (score 5):

**July 2021 (according to our logs):**

Mobile agent is the same as in Ghassan Maslamanis answer from February 2021.

Desktop user agent is now:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.175 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse
```

So they put the "Chrome-Lighthouse" back at the end of the string like they already did in May 2020 according to Oleg Kopachovets answer.

Answer (score 1):

This source (http://riskyinternet.com/google-page-speed-insights-tool-open-for-use-by-scammers/) suggests that the UA string looks like this:

“Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.8 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/19.0.1084.36 Safari/536.8”

Answer (score 1):

Dec - 2019

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

Current data for today:

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4590.2 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

### Update for March 2024

I just had to verify the answered above and can confirm that in 2024
Google is setting `Chrome-Lighthouse` in all of the following user agents ⬇️

### [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev)

**Mobile**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4590.2 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse`

**Desktop**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4590.2 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse`

### [Publisher Ads Audits for Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/publisher-ads-audits)

**Mobile**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse Google-AdSpeed-Insights`

**Desktop**

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse Google-AdSpeed-Insights`

---

**Note:** *It seems like `Chrome-Lighthouse` has been removed in this [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/14384) to avoid cheating here but it is currently still shown in the user agent.*

*The [recommended way](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/14917#issuecomment-1505718536) by Paul Irish is to use a query parameter like `?isLighthouse` for testing.*

Answer (score -1):

Checking the User Agent from Google Page Speed Insights these are the two instances of the service to check mobile and web

```
{   "pattern": "Chrome-Lighthouse",
    "instances": [
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse",
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"
    ]}
```

i'm using these object to validate with a regex if the user agent is a bot

```
regex = RegExp("Chrome-Lighthouse","ig")
regex.test("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse")
```

Answer (score -2):

This regex matches the UA as of the time of this answer:

```
// javascript PSI regex
navigator.userAgent.match(/nux.*oto\sG|x11.*fox\/54|x11.*ome\/39|x11.*ome\/62|oid\s6.*1.*xus\s5.*MRA58N.*ome|JWR66Y.*ome\/62|woobot|speed|ighth|tmetr|eadle/i)
// taken from WP plugin Fast Velocity Minify
```

Use it responsibly  and avoid using document.write if you plan to inject js.

Answer (score -3):

Check if we have

like Gecko

In $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']