# What is the user agent of Core Web Vitals?

Tags: user-agent, core-web-vitals

What is the user agent of the crawler, which delivers Core Web Vitals data into Google Search Console?

I can't find any info about, whether it is the same crawler of PageSpeed Insight, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403295/what-is-the-name-of-the-google-pagespeed-user-agent), or is it another crawler with different user agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no user agent for Core Web Vitals as the vitals are directly gathered from within Chrome. So basically all your visitors using a Chrome browser are checking your website and anonymously sending that data to Google.

This is called [CrUX data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520?hl=en) and that is what is displayed in Google Search Console, the live field data.

No bot/crawler involved in this process.

Comment: makes sense, thank you. Do you probably know about a source for Chrome version statistics, based on which is CrUX data gathered?

Comment: According to https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#usagestats all chromes from version 54 on do record that metrics. Just find a market share report that gives you the share of the different chrome versions, and you should have that info